# Read or move e-mail using GMail API (without IMAP)

Tags: api, gmail

I am wondering what Gmail APIs one would use to read, move or delete e-mail, noting that IMAP is disabled on most users' accounts by default.

To give you an idea - I tried out a couple of websites like  [OtherInbox](http://www.otherinbox.com/)  and  [email game](http://emailgame.baydin.com)  - making sure that IMAP was disabled on my account and these two sites still worked, which made me wonder that they were probably using some other API from gmail which I haven't been able to find.  Any ideas?

Thanks - I would appreciate any help on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that even if IMAP is disabled on the account, but, the user gives access to gmail to a website - the website can access the account as an IMAP client using the IMAP API calls, and, thus perform the basic actions of reading, moving and deleting e-mail.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time and writing the answer you found for your own question!